# In facebook privacy settings, what is the difference between regular and added audience for tagged posts?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-timeline, facebook-tags

What is the difference between the below two policy settings:

1) Who can see posts you've been tagged in on your timeline?

2) When you're tagged in a post, who do you want to add to the audience if they aren't already in it?

They seem very similar in nature to me.